# Experience Editor input with placeholder rendering issue in Sitecore

Tags: input, sitecore

this issue happened when a input DOM with placeholder in Sitecore Experience Editor, does someone know how to solve this?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="@Html.Sitecore().Field("Placeholder_Test")" value="123" />
</div>
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sitecore renders `@Html.Sitecore().Field` in Experience Editor mode, it adds extra html layout around the field value to allow content authors to edit the text.

So your generated output is something like that:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="<code attr="blah">aa</code><span>this is a text</span>" value="123" />
```

As you can see, this is not a valid html. And that's why you see incorrect output in Experience Editor.

What it means? That you cannot edit attributes of inputs inside Experience Editor using `@Html.Sitecore().Field`.

The simplest solution is to just render the value there, like (replace `Sitecore.Context.Item` with your datasource if needed):

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="@Sitecore.Context.Item["Placeholder_Test"]" value="123" />
```

And to use Edit Frame to allow editing the placeholder text ( https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore+edit+frame )

Comment: have one more question, the field data is from another Content(Template), the error shows Non-invocable memner 'Sitecore.Context.Item' cannot be used like a medoth.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you either add the code and the output to your question (+some screenshots maybe), or best create a new question with all the details.